# VSCode - LaTeX preview not working

Tags: preview, vscode, live-preview

When I try to preview any LaTeX document I write in VSCode, I get the error message
**Cannot view file PDF file. File not found C:....**
How can I fix this? It would be really convenient for me if I could get this fixed, as I write all my other code in VS.
I use Windows 10.

Comment: Which extension are you using for compiling LaTeX in VS Code?

Comment: I think you probably want to try this extension
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop